# Sort Numbers Numerically In a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I'm trying to sort numbers in a div in numerical order. But although the code looks ok, it's just not working. So I'm seeing if anyone has any ideas?

On the page there are multiple divs on a page in this format, all with the same class name.

```
<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
```

I'm trying to sort these numbers, in numerical order on page load. So I have stored them in an array and tried doing the .sort() function. But still hasn't worked.

```js
$(function() {
  let textArray = [];
  $('.class-numbers').contents().each(function () {
  textArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  textArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  console.log(textArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
```

The console log seems to console log the array of each div with class-numbers. But doesn't seem to sort them numerically?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to sort the numbers in each `.class-numbers` element you come across? Or do you want to collect ALL numbers in ALL elements? It is not clear from your code and question what you're trying to do, as the code indicates the latter, while the way you phrase your question indicates the former.

Comment: To sort each numbers in each .class-numbers i come across on the page.

Comment: You're pushing a single string to your array with `$(this).text()`, not the individual values

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And do you want to rewrite the contents of the div, after sorting the numbers?

Comment: @Terry Yeah I want to rewrite the contents of the div after sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, which you have clarified in your comments, you want to:

1. Perform sorting of comma-separated numbers in each `div.class-numbers` *individually*
2. Overwrite the text content of each div with the newly sorted numbers

It is pretty straightforward: you simply use `.text()` and [pass a function to it](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function), which will return the sorted array of numbers. `.text()` accepts a function and will use the return value to set the inner text of the element.

This is one of the "magical" things about jQuery, is that `.text()`, like many other methods, implicitly loops through the collection: you don't even need to use `.each()` first. These methods operates with *sets* of matched elements in mind, emphasis my own:

> Set the content of each element in **the set of matched elements** to the specified text.

This gives us the code of the following nature:

```
$('.class-numbers').text(function(_i, text) {
  return text.split(',').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }).join(',');
});
```

If you are familiar with ES6 though, we can squash all of this into a one-liner (sacrificing some readability, and loss of reference to `this`, which you will not need in this case anyway):

```
$('.class-numbers').text((_,t) => t.split(',').sort((a,b) => a-b).join(', '));
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$('.class-numbers').text((_,t) => t.split(',').sort((a,b) => a-b).join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
<div class="class-numbers">73, 16, 37, 22, 1</div>
```

There is always of course a native JS solution without needing jQuery ;)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.class-numbers').forEach(el => {
  el.textContent = el.textContent
    .split(',')
    .sort((a,b) => a-b)
    .join(', ');
});
```

```html
<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
<div class="class-numbers">73, 16, 37, 22, 1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Terry this works perfectly!

Comment: @Naffa Happy to help. I've updated my answer with some additional comments, and also condensed the code into a nifty one-liner, if you want a bit of a challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing a single string to your array with `$(this).text()`, not the individual values. Split the string with `textArray = $(this).text().split(',');`

Example:

```js
let textArray = [];
$('.class-numbers').each(function() {
  textArray = $(this).text().split(',');
  textArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  console.log(textArray);
  $(this).text(textArray.join(', '))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
<div class="class-numbers">9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1</div>
<div class="class-numbers">55, 11, 76, 2, 14</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly in the console log. How would I rewrite the contents of the div after it's sorted like this?

Comment: @Naffa With `$(this).text(textArray.join(', '))`. I've updated my example to show

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the text into elements before you sort them.

```js
textArray = $(this).text().split(', ')
```

You might want to convert them to numbers too.

```js
textArray = $(this).text().split(', ').map(it => parseInt(it))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery:

```js
  let textArray = document.querySelectorAll(".class-numbers")[0].innerText.split(', ');
  
textArray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<div class="class-numbers">14, 16, 18, 25, 3, 38, 41, 9</div>
```